# Can't Java GUI to look the way I want...?

Tags: java, swing, layout, joptionpane

Question just wants the GUI to look like this:

Here's the code I have

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Customer
  {

    String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name");
    String id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter id");
    String sub = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Submit");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, null, null, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE)

  }
```

}

I want it everything to look horizontal

```
Enter Name         [box to fill in name]

Enter id            [box to fill in id]

Submit              [box to enter submit]
```

Comment: Start with some light reading: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and you'll probably want [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: No worries, have fun ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're showing a total of 4 optionpanes. If you want everything in one optionpane, this might help:

```
JPanel msgPanel = new JPanel();
msgPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3 , 2));

msgPanel.add(new JLabel("Enter name");

JTextField nameField = new JTextField();
msgPanel.add(nameField);

//create other fields and labels

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , msgPanel , "" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

String name = nameField.getText();
//read other fields
```